What does "42" mean in the opening credits?
In the beginning of Spider-Man Into the Spider-Verse (2018) Alt Universe,
A ball with the number 42 on it is shown on the screen:

What does "42" mean in the opening credits?

HHGTTG reference?

@Jontia -https://gamerant.com/spider-man-across-the-spider-verse-number-42-explained/ surprisingly no.

@Valorum How can someone write an article about the meaning of 42 and not even mention H2G2, even if it is to say that H2G2 is not the reference being made!

The number 42 is a recurring element in the Spiderverse movies, appearing both textually as the universe of origin for the spider that bites Earth-1610 Miles Morales and as a purely "random" number which appears in scenes for no clear in-universe reason as easter eggs. According to co-director Peter Ramsay in a 2020 Business Insider interview, they chose the number 42 because:

Forty-two was Jackie Robinson's jersey number for the Brooklyn
Dodgers. He was a barrier-smashing black superhero in baseball, and
[Miles is a] color-smashing black superhero in Spider-Man comics.

